# How can I get my fees back when I had the error: "warning error encountered during contract execution"

Tags: gas, fees

How can I get my fees back when I had the error: "warning  error encountered during contract execution" I mad the transaction with Metamask. And paid 80 dollars. And I want the have the 80 Dollars back. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The gas fee is the financial incentive for the miners to process your tx and include it into a block. As your tx was processed, it was picked up, executed and included into a block, you paid the fee.

The fact that the tx fails is none of the miner's concern.

Forget those 80 dollars, they belong to the miner now. That's the deal you implicitly accept when sending a tx.

Answer (score 0):

There are practically no ways to get the tx eth back. Miners are not responsible if there is anything wrong with the contract. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As previously said, all the gas consume by txs you send is consume and can't be refund. There are multiple situations where it can happens : if your tx is reverted, if you set a too low gas limit...

The only case where gas is refund is when your tx use less gas then the amount specify in gas limit, here you will retrieve the difference.

You can save gas by calling estimateGas on your tx, it will exec the tx to estimate the gas and if your tx fail during the estimation, no gas will be lost and you will know that it will fail if you try to mine it.

Answer (score 0):

No way of getting it back. Always use a test net first to make sure everything is good as can be.